# Find all integral solutions to $xy^2 + (x^2 + 1)y + x^4 + 1 = 0$.

Tags: polynomials, algorithms, diophantine-equations, maple, computer-algebra-systems

I have an equation $$xy^2 + (x^2 + 1)y + x^4 + 1 = 0$$ and I need to find a set of solutions for it in integers. I tried to solve it using Maple with the `isolve ()` command, but it doesn’t give anything. This suggests that either the Maple algorithms cannot solve it or that there are no solutions. However, I know that he is resolved. Maybe you know special algorithms for solving this equation or other methods?

Comment: I would solve the equation for $$y$$

Comment: Don't know if it helps that much, but if you look at the discriminant (of the quadratic on $y$) you get that $x<1$

Answer (score 1):

This answer makes use of the rational root theorem a lot. Let $x$ and $y$ be integers such that
$$xy^2 + (x^2 + 1)y + x^4 + 1 = 0.\tag{1}$$
We first make a few simple observations.

1. If $x=0$ then $y=-1$, and if $y=-1$ then $x=0$.
2. There are no other integral solutions with $|x|\leq2$.
3. Equation $(1)$ shows that $y$ divides $x^4+1$.

**Lemma 1:** *If $(x,y)$ is an integral solution to $(1)$, then there exists $u\in\Bbb{Z}$ such that*
$$y=ux^4-2x^3-x^2-x-1.$$

*Proof.* If $x=0$ then this follows from the first observation above. So suppose $x\neq0$. Viewing $(1)$ as a polynomial in $x$ we see that
$$x^4+yx^2+y^2x+y+1=0,$$
and hence that $x$ divides $y+1$. Let $z=\tfrac{y+1}{x}\in\Bbb{Z}$ so that plugging in $y=zx-1$ into $(1)$ yields
$$x^3+x^2z^2+x^2z-2xz-x+z+1=0.$$
this in turn shows that $x$ divides $z+1$. Let $w=\tfrac{z+1}{x}\in\Bbb{Z}$ so that plugging in $z=wx-1$ yields
$$w^2x^3-wx^2-2wx+w+x^2+1=0,$$
which in turn shows that $x$ divides $w+1$. Let $v=\tfrac{w+1}{x}\in\Bbb{Z}$ so that plugging in $w=vx-1$ yields
$$v^2x^4-2vx^3-vx^2-2vx+v+x^2+2x+2=0.$$
which in turn shows that $x$ divides $v+2$. Let $u=\tfrac{v+2}{x}\in\Bbb{Z}$ so that
\begin{eqnarray*}
y&=&zx-1=(wx-1)x-1=((vx-1)x-1)x-1\\
&=&(((ux-2)x-1)x-1)x-1\\
&=&ux^4-2x^3-x^2-x-1.\hspace{100pt}\square
\end{eqnarray*}

**Lemma 2:** *If $x\neq0$ then $|u|\leq1$.*

*Proof.* If $|u|>1$ then for all $x\notin\{-1,0,1,2\}$ we have
$$|y|=|ux^4-2x^3-x^2-x-1|>x^4+1,$$
contradicting the fact that $y$ divides $x^4+1$. As there are no integral solutions with $x\in\{-1,1,2\}$ it follows that $|u|\leq1$ if $x\neq0$.$\hspace{20pt}\square$

At this point we can simply try the three possible values of $u$ to get three polynomials in $x$, and see whether they have integral roots:

If $u=0$ then $y=-(2x^3+x^2+x+1)$. Plugging this back into $(1)$ yields
$$x^4(4x^3+4x^2+3x+6)=0,$$
and the rational root theorem shows that $x=0$ is the unique solution.

If $u=1$ then $y=x^4-2x^3-x^2-x-1$. Plugging this back into $(1)$ yields
$$x^4(x^2+1)(x^3-4x^2+x+7)=0,$$
which again has $x=0$ as its unique integral solution by the rational root theorem.

If $u=-1$ then $y=-x^4-2x^3-x^2-x-1$. Plugging this back into $(1)$ yields
$$x^4(x^5+4x^4+6x^3+5x^2+5x+5)=0,$$
which again has $x=0$ as its unique integral solution by the rational root theorem.

This shows that $(x,y)=(0,-1)$ is the unique integral solution to $(1)$.